# What does $M(P^T)$ mean?

Tags: linear-algebra

I've just came across the following problem:

> Suppose $P_{k \times m}$ is a matrix of rank $k$ such that $M(P^T) \subset M(X^T)$, where $X$ is of size $m \times n$. How can it be shown that $P (X^TX)^{-1} P^T$ is positive definite?

What does $M(P^T)$ mean?

Answer (score 0):

It's always difficult to say if the notation is not explained by the author, but my guess is:

The set of all matrices "like" $P^T$...to make the "like" part precise: of rank $k$ and order $m \times k$.

The reason why I say so, $M_{m \times k}(\mathbb{F})$ is usually used to indicate the set of matrices of order $m \times k$ over the field $\mathbb{F}$. In this case the subscript $m \times k$ is not needed as the order of $P$ is given (and hence of $P^T$ is known), the field over which the matrix $P$ is, is not indicated, but might be apparent from the context, and the rank of the matrix is specified. $P^T$ is of course just the transpose of $P$...so putting all this together, that would be my best guess.